# why am I getting negative Area under curve?

Tags: python, numpy

I computed the tpr and fpr arrays based upon the actual class-label , probability scores and threshold values and after that I used `auc = np.trapz(tpr_array, fpr_array)` to calculate Area under curve (AUC) for this problem, but if I visualize it seems pretty obvious AUC value should be positive but by using `numpy.trapz` function what I get is a negative value, I am not sure how could this be possible.

[negative area under curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLkfK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 1):

Integrals swap signs when you swap the order:

```
np.trapz([0,1], [0,1]) # 0.5
np.trapz([1,0], [1,0]) # -0.5
```

most likely your tpr and fpr are ordered the wrong way.